# Can't figure out what is causing my viewport to scroll to the right

Tags: css, html5-canvas, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to figure out what is causing my banner (or header) to be pushed to the right if you view at 1920px width resolution. I've looked at the code but can't find out what's wrong. It's causing scrollbars at the bottom of the viewport.

[Live link here](http://ogmda.com/si2s/index2.html)

Here's a screenshot of the area I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is your issue

`.row {margin-right: -15px;}`

remove the negative margin left.

fyi, you should probably remove the negative `margin-left` as well.

Comment: THanks, but that's bootstrap default. THere's got to be another way.

Comment: I saw this note in the Bootstrap 3 documentation. Does it pertain to my situation? "Folks looking to create fully fluid layouts (meaning your site stretches the entire width of the viewport) must wrap their grid content in a containing element with padding: 0 15px; to offset the margin: 0 -15px; used on .rows."